Remove old files in subfolders and subfolders
I have an ip cam that records videos in a folder structure like this:
├── 2023
│   ├── 10
│   ├── 11
│   │   ├── cam_00_20240921153706.mp4
│   │   ├── cam_00_20240921153928.mp4
│   │   ├── cam_00_20240921164743.mp4
│   │   └── cam_00_20240921230558.mp4
│   └── 12
└── 2024
    ├── 08
    └── 09
        ├── 21
        │   ├── cam_00_20240921153706.mp4
        │   ├── cam_00_20240921153928.mp4
        │   ├── cam_00_20240921164743.mp4
        │   ├── cam_00_20240921230558.mp4
        │   └── cam_00_20240921230646.mp4
        └── 22
            ├── cam_00_20240922101839.mp4
            └── cam_00_20240922102150.mp4

Now I would like to delete all files that are older than 2 days, and all empty folders.
To do this, I did
#delete files older than 2 days
find /recordings/????/??/?? -depth -type d -mtime +2 -exec rm -rf {} \;
#delete empty month dir
find /recordings/????/?? -depth -empty -type d -mtime +2 -exec rm -rf {} \;
#delete empty year dir
find /recordings/???? -depth -empty -type d -mtime +2 -exec rm -rf {} \;

Can this be done with a one liner? Or in a nicer way?

In your commands you all the time deal with directories, not files: -type d 

and rm - rf can be really dangerous. why not just rm -r if you only delete folders instead of files?

find has a -o (or) parameter, that allows combining two commands:
find /recordings/ -type f -mtime +2 -exec rm -f {} \; -o -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;

Explanation:

find /recordings/ - Search recursively starting from the /recordings/ directory.
-type f -mtime +2 -exec rm -f {} \; - Find files older than 2 days and delete them.
-o - OR operator to combine different find expressions.
-type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \; - Find empty directories and remove them.

